# Programs opening in full-screen mode by default

Tags: firefox, fullscreen, filezilla

Since I upgraded from Ubuntu 16.04 to 18.04, both Filezilla and Firefox always open in full-screen mode, no matter how I have adjusted them before closing.

What can I do to change this annoying behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Either:

1. Double-click on the application's titlebar to minimize/maximize the window.
2. Use the GNOME Tweaks tool, and enable the following, and then click the little square icon in the top-right corner of the application's window.

[image]

**Update #1:**

In `terminal`...

```
cd ~/.mozilla/firefox                # change to firefox prefs directory

ls -al *.default                     # the one with the newest date is yours

cd {.default directory found before} # change to your user directory

ls -alt | grep "Oct 25"              # note which files changed today
```

one of these files is causing your problem...

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, I can change the size of the window by several different methods but, once set, I didn't used to have to.  Now I have to reduce the size of the Firefox and Filezilla windows every time I start these programs.  I installed Gnome-tweak-tool as you suggested and changed the settings but, still, the program behaviour is the same.  Every time I start the program, I have to reduce the size of its window from full screen.  Under Ubuntu 16.04, The programs remembered their settings and I never had to change the window size, once adjusted.

Comment: OK, lets eliminate something in your home directory. Create a new user called "Guest" (or whatever). Log out of your normal account, and into the Guest account. See if Firefox behaves as you desire. Report back.

Comment: Yes!  Created new account and Firefox window opens in whatever size it had when I last closed it.  Filezilla, on the other hand, opened the first time in a somewhat reduced size but thereafter opens full-screen no matter what.  At least Firefox behaves properly.  What does that tell you and how can I apply that to my own account?

Comment: @ve3oat see the update in my answer. You'll have to do a little work to find the specific culprit. Please remember to accept my answer if it was helpful. Thanks!

Comment: @ve3oat in the Firefox address bar, type `about:config`, then search for `window`, note anything found that's listed in bold font... they may be your problem.

Comment: Sorry for the delay (suddenly very busy here).  Have just tried "about:config" and searching for window -- found 39 entries, all listed as "default" values.  The meanings of some of them escapes me but these two seemed relevant :   browser.link.open_newwindow;default;integer;3
browser.link.open_newwindow.disabled_in_fullscreen;default;boolean;false.  Should I look for something else or more specific?  Thanks.

Comment: @ve3oat you should be looking for something that's in bold font, as that indicates that the value has been changed from default.

Comment: There was nothing in bold font and all the values were listed as "default".  But, before I started work, Software Updater wanted to do a small update.  This morning when I turned on the computer, Firefox started at less than full-screen, just the way I had closed it last night.  This continues today, so the problem has been solved for Firefox.  Thanks for your help with this.  I don't know what caused the problem, I have certainly learned a bit in the process, thanks to your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with Firefox has been solved by software update.  Don't know if it was a Firefox problem or something in Ubuntu.  Problem with Filezilla always opening at full-screen continues but I can live with that.  Thanks for all your suggestions -- it has been a learning experience for me.